# Specify password when connecting to a Samba share

Tags: catalina, smb

I can connect to a Samba share on my Raspberry Pi with the following:-

```
open smb://MilliwaysPi4.local/pi
```

This then prompts for a password.
macOS offers to remember the password in Keychain, BUT this still needs to be confirmed, and it attempts to use my macOS username, so needs to be edited.

Is there a way to specify the password in the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a username and password before the domain name:

```
open smb://username:password@MilliwaysPi4.local/pi
```